# PDO BindValue - Array Where

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Boa tarde.

Estou criando um formulário onde o usuário seleciona alguns campos para formular uma consulta e assim gerar um sql para ser executado e retornado.

Após validar os campos, eu crio um array $array_whare e insiro todo os campos selecionados no formulário, conforme exemplo:

cliente.id_cliente='7' and tecnico.id_tecnico = '11' and chamado.data_encerramento between '2019-01-01 00:00:00' and '2019-01-31 23:59:00'' (length=139)

Sendo assim, eu envio para a função que insere em uma variável $sql por meio do bindValue a variável $array_where:

```
$sql = 'select
                    chamado.num_chamado,
                    cliente.nome_fantasia,
                    equipamento.num_serie ,
                    tecnico.nome_tecnico,
                    tipo_servico.tipo_servico ,
                    chamado.cont_inicial,
                    chamado.cont_final ,
                    chamado.data_abertura ,
                    chamado.data_encerramento ,
                    chamado.solicitante ,
                    chamado.servico_solicitado ,
                    status_chamado.tipo_status,
                    atividade_chamado.data_inicio ,
                    atividade_chamado.data_final_atend ,
                    atividade_chamado.relatorio_tecnico 
                from
                    chamado
                    inner join equipamento on equipamento.id_equipamento = chamado.equipamento_id_equipamento
                    inner join tipo_servico on tipo_servico.id_tipo_servico = chamado.tipo_servico_id_tipo_servico
                    inner join atividade_chamado on atividade_chamado.chamado_id_chamado = chamado.id_chamado
                    inner join tecnico_has_atividade_chamado on tecnico_has_atividade_chamado.atividade_chamado_id_atividade = atividade_chamado.id_atividade
                    inner join tecnico on tecnico.id_tecnico = tecnico_has_atividade_chamado.tecnico_id_tecnico
                    inner join contrato on contrato.id_contrato = equipamento.contrato_id_contrato
                    inner join cliente on cliente.id_cliente = contrato.cliente_id_cliente
                    inner join status_chamado on status_chamado.id_status_chamado = chamado.status_chamado_id_status_chamado
                    inner join usuario on usuario.id_usuario = chamado.usuario_id_usuario
                where
                :Array_where;';
        $stmt = Conexaodb::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':Array_where', $array_where, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Após executar o $stmt o select não retorna nenhuma resultado e também não da erro.
Para verificar, criei o SQL todo antes de enviar para a função, concatenando em um array o inicio do SQL, até o where, e posteriormente as clausulas where que o usuário escolheu e enviei para a função executar. na função alterei de prepare($sql) para query($sql) e o seleect retornou o resultado normalmente.

Resumindo, queria saber se tem algum bloqueio com PDO que não aceita eu substituir do value por algo no padrão SQL, tipo tabela.coluna= valor? Testei com baindParam, BindValue, alterei o PARAM_STR, PARAM_STR_CHAR e etc e mesmo assim não conseguir usar.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Dessa forma não é possível, teria que fazer um a um.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível utilizar o bindValue para criar regras inteiras, pois a query é enviada para o servidor prepara-la e depois os valores são enviados separados. O seu array_where não está sendo "concatenado" com a consulta, e sim enviado como um valor.

Recomendo que procure como funcionam prepared statements.

Para o que você está tentando fazer, sugiro concatenar diretamente as condições na string da query(não é uma boa pratica, pois abre espaço para ataques de sql injection), ou melhor ainda, separar as condições e fazer um bind para cada valor.

```
$sql = "select
                    chamado.num_chamado,
                    cliente.nome_fantasia,
                    equipamento.num_serie ,
                    tecnico.nome_tecnico,
                    tipo_servico.tipo_servico ,
                    chamado.cont_inicial,
                    chamado.cont_final ,
                    chamado.data_abertura ,
                    chamado.data_encerramento ,
                    chamado.solicitante ,
                    chamado.servico_solicitado ,
                    status_chamado.tipo_status,
                    atividade_chamado.data_inicio ,
                    atividade_chamado.data_final_atend ,
                    atividade_chamado.relatorio_tecnico 
                from
                    chamado
                    inner join equipamento on equipamento.id_equipamento = chamado.equipamento_id_equipamento
                    inner join tipo_servico on tipo_servico.id_tipo_servico = chamado.tipo_servico_id_tipo_servico
                    inner join atividade_chamado on atividade_chamado.chamado_id_chamado = chamado.id_chamado
                    inner join tecnico_has_atividade_chamado on tecnico_has_atividade_chamado.atividade_chamado_id_atividade = atividade_chamado.id_atividade
                    inner join tecnico on tecnico.id_tecnico = tecnico_has_atividade_chamado.tecnico_id_tecnico
                    inner join contrato on contrato.id_contrato = equipamento.contrato_id_contrato
                    inner join cliente on cliente.id_cliente = contrato.cliente_id_cliente
                    inner join status_chamado on status_chamado.id_status_chamado = chamado.status_chamado_id_status_chamado
                    inner join usuario on usuario.id_usuario = chamado.usuario_id_usuario
                where
                {$array_where}";
        $stmt = Conexaodb::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Foi o que imaginei. Acho que vou criar um array com os inputs e seu valores e enviar para o bind e criar um foreach para inserir o campo  e depois o valor. Obrigado pelo retorno.